# iOS 8 : popViewControllerAnimated & popToRootViewControllerAnimated not workring

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, popviewcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I am getting one error in iOS 8 in Xcode 6.

Just here is the scenario.

XCode 6 create new Project "Master-Detail Application"

Now I have doing just in detail add one button and in its click event view to Pop Master view but it's not working.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Please have a look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the exact same problem, except for me "popViewControllerAnimated" doesn't work, while "popToRootViewControllerAnimated" does work! If none are working for you, double check that self.navigationController is not nil.

Answer (score 3):

When using a `splitViewController` in a Master-Detail application, accessing the navigation controller can be tricky.

This is what I had to do in Swift. Essentially I'm referencing the top view controller of my `splitViewController` and then casting it as a `UINavigationController`:

```
if let navController = splitViewController?.viewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController{
  navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Off the top of my head, the Objective-C equivalent would be:

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
[navcontroller popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I hope that helps.